# How to copy values, not references, of List<Integer> into another list?

Tags: java, arraylist

Namely, without referencing the same object, I need to copy values of elements of one list into another list. These are the lists:

```
List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> ListB = new ArrayList<Integer>();

listA = (added some values);

listB = (do what?)...
```

PS. I appologize for beginner's question, but I have never done such a thing.

Comment: You mean you need to copy the objects onto the same list? Deep copy? Sou you have identical objects in the lists but not the same reference?

Comment: @pfh To copy Integer values from one list into another. Not references.

Comment: Using Integer class you will use objects(references), not values(primitives). Below, check it out, you might find yourself in problems when "copying" the objects. Integer and the other "boxed" classes are immutable, but really it's a boxed int referenced by List.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try and give a look at the [Collections.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) method:

> public static  void copy(List dest,
>               List src)
>
> Copies all of the elements from one list into another. After the operation, the index of each copied
>   element in the destination list will be identical to its index in the
>   source list. The destination list must be at least as long as the
>   source list. If it is longer, the remaining elements in the
>   destination list are unaffected. This method runs in linear time.
>
> Parameters: dest - The destination list. src - The source list.

Note: The above should work for simple data types such as Integers, however, if you have your own objects which might in turn reference other objects, you will have to iterate over each object and copy it separately.

Comment: Looks great. The descr does not say if this copies values or references?

Comment: @sandalone: As far as I know, this should perform a shallow copy, meaning that the Integers will be copied. However, as stated in my answer, more complex objects will require you to iterate over them and copy them one by one.

Comment: This isn't references, it'll copies of the objects from second ArrayList.

Comment: @sandalone: Yes, as per the documentation, you need to initialize it to the same size prior to copying.

Answer (score 36):

There is absolutely no reason to make a copy of an Integer. Integer is an immutable class. This means that its value is set when the Integer instance is created, and can never change. An Integer reference can thus be shared by multiple lists and threads without fear, because there's no way anybody can change its value. Your question thus makes no real sense.

To create an ArrayList `b` containing the same Integers as another List `a`, just use the following code:

```
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
```

Sure the Integer won't be cloned, but this is a good thing, because cloning them is completely unnecessary.

Comment: But this way, clearing a list b will clear list a as well, right? I want to prevent this as list one of these list is a backup list.

Comment: Why would it? You have two list instances. What you do with one doesn't affect the other. The javadoc for this constructor says: *Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.*

Comment: I dont know why this isnt the answer

Answer (score 7):

Use this [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) of `Collections` class to copy all elements of ArrayList to another ArrayList:

```
Collections.copy(listA, listB);
```

Comment: Should be Collections.copy(destination, source);  fyi, so other way around

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this, while the answers given by another guys are totally fine. But per my option, the following would be the best way:

```
List<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>(listA);
```

Comment: won't this copy references only?

Comment: This, Collections.copy() - it will copy references. Depends what you really need.

Comment: This will copy the element as a reference.

Comment: @sandalone Copying references to the `Integer` objects is what we want. The accepted answer does too, which I take to mean that this is OK with the OP, even though the wording of the question might have been understood otherwise. Creating new `Integer` objects would be meaningless, as JB Nizet said in his answer, and is only possible through the deprecated constructor.

Answer (score 2):

For clarification.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
ArrayList<Integer> c = a;
          
c.set(0, 5);
    
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

Will print out

```
[5, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[5, 2, 3]
```

Using the new keyword will automatically take the values from an existing array and copy those to the new array.

I'm also just a little bit confused as to why Collections.copy(dest, src) is listed on here as an answer. Considering if the new array has just been initialized you'll get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
```

This happens because Collections.copy uses List<> instead of ArrayList<> so if the source array is larger than the destination array you'll get this error. There ARE workarounds, such as a for loop to add X number of elements for Y number of elements in the first array but considering you can just use the new keyword and all this gets done automatically I feel as if this answer should be changed to be JB Nizet's answer.

I also made sure to actually run this code so all of this is up to date as of Java: 1.8.0_333

Answer (score -1):

You won't have a lot of luck with clone() and Cloneable - it will only create a shallow copy. You could use something like this - http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/ .

Answer (score -3):

Try This.

```
ListB.addAll(listA);
```

Comment: This will not create copies of the objects - it will copy references.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I think the question is ambiguous. IMO the OP is talking about the reference *to the list*, not about references to the *elements of the list*. I first read the question the way you did, but now I am leaning towards the other interpretation.